# ETCD restore granularity

Tags: backup, kubernetes, etcd

I'm studying some backup and restore solutions for Kubernetes and Openshift, typically with Velero. So, I'm not familiar with ETCD backups, but I would like to ask about the granularity level of etcd snapshots restore. Does ETCD snapshots only allow to restore the cluster state as a whole? or we can restore some specific objects like namespaces, deployments, pod, pvc, etc? In another way, can ETCD backups do the same job as velero (except what concerns volumes) or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Etcd snapshots and restore are not meant for partial recovery, it's all or nothing.

However you may use an etcd snapshot to retrieve those data you've lost and re-create them in your cluster, without resetting etcd.

One way to do so would be to restore your etcd database into a container, on your workstation. Start a container, eg:

```
docker -v $(pwd)/restore-path:/restore run --entrypoint /bin/sh -it quay.io/coreos/etcd:vX.Y.Z
```

Restore your snapshot, start etcd, then query it:

```
etcdctl snapshot restore /restore/snapshot.db 
etcd --name default --listen-client-urls http://localhost:2379  --advertise-client-urls http://localhost:2379 --listen-peer-urls http://localhost:2380 &
etcdctl get / --prefix --keys-only
```

You should get back the list of objects, as stored in etcd. Now try to locate the objects you want to restore:

```
etcdctl get / --prefix --keys-only | grep my-object-name

etcdctl get /kubernetes.io/configmaps/my-namespace/lost-config  --print-value-only | tee -a /restore/my-lost-config.out
```

This output is a bit messy, as it would return some non-printable characters alongside your YAML. Still it should be good enough recovering a few objects. Otherwise you can look into something like Augher (https://github.com/jpbetz/auger), which should clean this up for you, if you need something robust scripting such recoveries, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take etcd backup in JSON format that you can easily restore to any cluster, you can use this simple backup and restore utility that I have developed: [simple-etcd-backup-restore](https://github.com/abdullahkhawer/simple-etcd-backup-restore)

This utility makes the backup and restore process easier and faster. You can also compress/decompress the backup file and upload/download it on/from AWS S3 bucket. The size of backup files also gets smaller. Data in the backup files stays readable as well.

Comment: Spooky :) I'm not sure JSON formatting is the most efficient way to backup an etcd database, keeping in mind compressed database size can grow several gigs, etcd snapshots utilities would definitely be faster and more efficient. And probably safer as well -- evals, sed, ... pretty sure we can craft some valid k8s object that could break your magic

Comment: @SYN I won't disagree. :)